# Why would a lay investor care about a Leveraged ETF's Exposure Before and After Reset?

Tags: finance

I don't understand [the "Exposure Before Reset" and "Exposure After Reset" columns below](https://www.etf.com/sections/features-and-news/etf-education-problem-inverseleveraged-etfs). To wit, why multiply by $-2$ the:

1. Index Level?
2. The $-2X$ ETF Index Level?
3. Doesn't the Leveraged ETF owner care merely about the "Level" column?

I'm not asking about multiplication; I can deduce that eg. on Day 2, $110 \times -2 = 220$ and $80 \times -2 = -160$.

Rather, why multiply

[image]

Comment: I am not entirely sure what your question is. The phrase “why multiply y-2” is hard to parse.

Answer (score 1):

It’s a 2x levered ETF. It has an exposure that is -2 times the size of the fund. The exposure determines how much the fund gains  or loses in response to a change in the underlying asset.

Since the exposure is 2x the assets in the fund, the exposure needs to reset daily. That is what the table demonstrates.